# Turn off global-flycheck-mode for org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, flycheck

Given I'd like to keep using `global-flycheck-mode`, how can I make sure flycheck is automatically disabled when editing org-mode documents? Or maybe is just activate it for code blocks?

I found [this discussion](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/723) but I admit I don't know what to do with this information. :\

---

***ORIGINAL QUESTION:***

I'm trying to create a timestamp with both date and time in org-mode (without adding to agenda), and I read from [the docs](http://orgmode.org/manual/Creating-timestamps.html) that I should be using this cord:

> C-u C-c !

However, I get this in my minibuffer:

[screenshot http://zc.d.pr/NxKK/56UjyS0K+](http://zc.d.pr/NxKK/56UjyS0K+)

Seems like its waiting for more input. I'm an Emacs n00b so I'm not really sure what's happening here. I get the same behavior with

> C-c !

Both versions with `.` work fine, though:

> C-u C-c .
>
> C-c .

What's happening here?

---

**UPDATE**: Thanks to suggestions from the comments below, I've determined Flycheck is doing something to screw this up: here's my flycheck config

```
(use-package flycheck
  :ensure t
  :init (global-flycheck-mode))
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
```

Where can I look to find if there is a colliding key binding?

Comment: `M-x where-is <RET> org-time-stamp-inactive` will show if it has a keybinding.

Comment: What you see in the echo area indicates that there is another keybinding `C-c ! (something)` defined somewhere, and Emacs is waiting for you to complete the combination.  First try it after starting Emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q`).  After that, bisect your init file recursively (commenting out successive halves) until what is creating the additional keybinding.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the insight. I've updated my post above with my findings... appears that Flycheck is the culprit, but I don't know how to fix yet. Would appreciate any insight to debugging these sorts of issues.

Answer (score 9):

I just did this by customizing flycheck-global-modes to be `'(not org-mode)`.

In the customize interface, that was clicking `except` and `repeat` and adding an `org-mode` entry.

Answer (score 1):

The prefix for flycheck commands is controlled by the `flycheck-keymap-prefix` variable. You can use [customize](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html) to set this to your liking. If you don't use customize note that [changing the value of `flycheck-keymap-prefix` is insufficient](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/blob/db3a745edb6b2678286e4d2bccebbb8d388c1a9e/flycheck.el#L853):

> Changing this variable outside Customize does not have any
>   effect.  To change the keymap prefix from Lisp, you need to
>   explicitly re-define the prefix key:
>
> ```
> (define-key flycheck-mode-map flycheck-keymap-prefix nil)
> (setq flycheck-keymap-prefix (kbd "C-c f"))
> (define-key flycheck-mode-map flycheck-keymap-prefix
>             flycheck-command-map)
> ```
>
> Please note that Flycheck's manual documents the default
>   keybindings.  Changing this variable is at your own risk.